# How to read all direct messages from a user in discord using python

Tags: python, discord

I have been making AI art recently using Midjourney and am aiming to organize all the creations I have made. I have the paid subscription that allows me to message the Midjourney Discord bot directly, so all of my images are in that conversation thread with the bot. My goal is to read each message and download the associated image with it as to catalog the different images. I would be using Python to do so since I have made a discord bot in the past.

I wanted to see if anyone has any thoughts as to how to go about retrieving this data. Once I have a way to access the direct messages I can take it from there -- it is the initial step of how to bring the messages into my script that has me stumped.